# Birthday in Contacts app not showing up in Google Calendar

Tags: contacts, calendar, google-calendar

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

I have a few people with registered birthdays in the Contacts app (the default Contacts app that came with my phone).

However, these birthdays are not showing up in the Google Calendar app.

Why is this?

What can I do to have Google Calendar automatically show birthdays from my Contacts app?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Calendars only shows birthdays from contacts stored in Google Account's Contacts. Thus, if Realme's Contacts app not storing the contacts on Google Account, then they can't be shown. Not sure about a 3rd-party app solution.